# Model's property not recognized by xaml (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvmcross

Using mvvmCross, .net (5.0), visual studio 19

View model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using MvxR_M_S.Core.API;
using MvxR_M_S.Core.Models;

namespace MvxR_M_S.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class ArticlePresentationViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public ArticlePresentationViewModel()
        {
        }

        public override async void ViewAppeared()
        {
            base.ViewAppeared();
            await LoadArticles(new ArticleEndpoint(new APIHelper()));
        }

        public async Task LoadArticles(ArticleEndpoint articleEndpoint)
        {
            var articleList = await articleEndpoint.GetAll();
            Articles = new BindingList<ArticleModel>(articleList);
        }

        private BindingList<ArticleModel> _articles;

        public BindingList<ArticleModel> Articles
        {
            get { return _articles; }
            set
            {
                _articles = value;
                SetProperty(ref _articles, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MvxR_M_S.Core.Models
{
    public class ArticleModel
    {
        public string ArticleName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<views:MvxWpfView
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Binding;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
    x:Class="MvxR_M_S.Wpf.Views.ArticlePresentationView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MvxR_M_S.Core.Models;assembly=MvxR_M_S.Core"
                 xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MvxR_M_S.Core.ViewModels;assembly=MvxR_M_S.Core"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" FontSize="20" Background="Wheat"
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Article list" />

        <ListBox x:Name="Articles" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="300" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxWpfView>
```

The problem is at the listbox, where it references **ItemsSource** right, also i did debug at the **Articles** property inside ViewModel, it holds right information, but nothing is presented on screen when started up.

So i guess this is binding issue.

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a TextBlock's Text Binding is pointless. Both setting do not have any effect in the Binding.

Comment: Is the DataContext of the view set to an instance of the ArticlePresentationViewModel class? Do you observe any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application?

Comment: thanks for the note. I think it is, but i am not positive. Speaking of observing binding errors, I did check by changing list box binding (instead of **Articles** i'd write **Article**, and it would throw an error - 'Article' property not found on 'object' ''ArticlePresentationViewModel').

Comment: And when you debug the LoadArticles method, the Articles property isn't empty?

Comment: No, I have 2 rows in test db, so 2 items, each with ArticleName property (as in Model)

Comment: Clemens no, the mode is in TwoWay by default but the UpdateSourceTrigger is LostFocus by default

Comment: Remove "_articles = value;" in Articles setter. I'll guess SetProperty doesn't do anything if the field already is set.

Comment: @PierreMichel You are confusing TextBlock and TextBox

Comment: @RolandJS that's it. SetValue checks if the backing field equals `value`. Write an answer!

Comment: Yes! I can see items now, thanks @RolandJS!

Comment: @Clemens again you are right, I will study more before commenting and answering ahah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `_articles = value;` in Articles setter. SetProperty doesn't do anything if the field already is set

```
public BindingList<ArticleModel> Articles
    {
        get { return _articles; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _articles, value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving the articles in a separate thread, I think you have to do something like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>  Articles = new BindingList<ArticleModel>(articleList);));
```

I am not exactly sure if it's the right way but `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` seems needed from what I found

Comment: Where exactly is that Thread? `await LoadArticles(...)` does not mean that it runs on a different thread.

Comment: The LoadArticles method is async and using await so I guess articleEndpoint.GetAll(); is in another thread which seems logic if it's calling an api

Comment: That is a big misconception. Even if there would be some background thread, the expression `Articles = new BindingList...` is executed *after* `articleEndpoint.GetAll()` had been awaited, so definitely in the UI thread.

Comment: When you are right you are right. I didn't fully understood async and await so I read some infos just now, I think I understand better